# I have a question related to a trip to London - is it on topic for Travel?

Tags: discussion, scope

Here's my (potential) question:

> I'm travelling to London in early November for an overnight trip, during which I'm visiting the Odeon in Leicester Square and the Apollo Victoria.
>
> Will I have any problems taking a small overnight bag into either of these places, and if so, where would the nearest luggage drops be?

Is it on topic here?  If it's not, can it be rephrased to make it so?

Comment: I think it's on topic. I carry a man bag with medical supplies and other stuff into the Odeon all the time. I haven't been to the Apollo Victoria but after all it's the Apollo *Victoria* meaning it's next door to Victoria Station. I doubt they would have a problem with it though.

Comment: Depending on the answer you might also find this related (non-dupe) question useful: [Cheap places to store bags in London for a few hours?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14612/cheap-places-to-store-bags-in-london-for-a-few-hours/)

Comment: ok, well based on those comments (thanks!) I've posed [the question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57469/can-i-take-an-overnight-bag-into-the-theatre-cinema-in-london)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go ahead and ask. The question is IMHO on topic for Travel SE. You can also answer it yourself ([as you've already done](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14612/cheap-places-to-store-bags-in-london-for-a-few-hours/)), and don't forget to come back and add more information once you complete the trip.